# Ambiguous type variable `a0' arising from a use of `getFromInt' prevents the constraint `(GetFromIntable a0)' from being solved. というエラーがでる

Tags: haskell

type classの学習のために、かなり人工的ですが下記のようなコードを書いてみたところ、`Showable`, `Changeable`は機能しているのですが、`GetFromIntable`が機能していないようでエラーになりました。

### コード

```
data Color = Red | Green

class Showable a where
  myshow :: a -> String

class Changeable a where
  change :: a -> a
  
class GetFromIntable a where
  getFromInt :: Int -> a
 
instance Showable Color where
  myshow Red = "AKA"
  myshow Green = "MIDORI"

instance Changeable Color where
  change Red = Green
  change Green = Red
  
instance GetFromIntable Color where
  getFromInt 1 = Red
  getFromInt 2 = Green

romajiRed = myshow Red
changedRomajiColor = myshow $ change Red
color = myshow $ getFromInt 1

main = do print $ romajiRed
          print $ changedRomajiColor
          print $ color
```

### 実行結果

```
% docker run -it --rm --name bar-haskell -v "$PWD":/tmp -w /tmp haskell:8 runghc Bar.hs

Bar.hs:26:9: error:
    * Ambiguous type variable `a0' arising from a use of `myshow'
      prevents the constraint `(Showable a0)' from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what `a0' should be.
      These potential instance exist:
        instance Showable Color -- Defined at Bar.hs:12:10
    * In the expression: myshow $ getFromInt 1
      In an equation for `color': color = myshow $ getFromInt 1
   |
26 | color = myshow $ getFromInt 1
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Bar.hs:26:18: error:
    * Ambiguous type variable `a0' arising from a use of `getFromInt'
      prevents the constraint `(GetFromIntable a0)' from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what `a0' should be.
      These potential instance exist:
        instance GetFromIntable Color -- Defined at Bar.hs:20:10
    * In the second argument of `($)', namely `getFromInt 1'
      In the expression: myshow $ getFromInt 1
      In an equation for `color': color = myshow $ getFromInt 1
   |
26 | color = myshow $ getFromInt 1
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

#### コードの説明

- Showable

  - myshowを実装することを要求する
  - Colorでは色に応じたローマ字を生成して返す（RedならAKA, GreenならMIDORI）
- Changeable

  - changeを実装することを要求する
  - ColorではRedとGreenを入れ替える処理として実装
- GetFromIntable

  - getFromIntを実装することを要求する
  - Colorでは1のときRed, 2のときGreenを返す処理として実装

### うまくいく例

type classを用いずに下記のようにすると

```
f 1 = Red
color = myshow $ f 1

main = do print $ romajiRed
          print $ changedRomajiColor
          print $ color
```

ちゃんと実行されました。なぜ、type classだとエラーになっているのでしょう？

```
% docker run -it --rm --name bar-haskell -v "$PWD":/tmp -w /tmp haskell:8 runghc Bar.hs
"AKA"
"MIDORI"
"AKA"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getFromInt` は `Int` を受け取って，`GetFromIntable` な何かの型 `a` の値を返します． `myshow` は `Showable` な何かの型 `a` の値を受け取って，`String` を返します．

型の指定をせずに `myshow $ getFromInt 1` を書いたとき，ここの `getFromInt` はなんの値を返せばよいでしょうか？ `GetFromIntable` で， `Showable` ならなんでもいい，はずです．

というわけで，型推論についていえば上記のコードの型が決定できないということになり，エラーが生じています．このコードでは `Color` について `GetFromIntable` と `Showable` のインスタンスと定義されていて，これが我々の意図ですが，まさにそうであることはコンパイラに教えてあげる必要があります．ほかの，たとえば `changedRomajiColor = myshow $ change Red` については，`Red` の存在によって順に型が一意にきまり，こうした問題は生じません．

解決はエラーメッセージに書いてあるとおり

> Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what `a0' should be.

ということで，アノテーションをつけてやればよいです（エラーメッセージには `instance Showable Color` の存在も指摘されており，親切です）．

具体的には、次のように`getFromInt`に型注釈を付けましょう:

```hs
color = myshow (getFromInt 1 :: Color)
```

Comment: 型アノテーションをどのように付けたら良いのかわかりませんでした。`color :: String` ではエラーのままでした。そもそも 、エラーメッセージにある`a0`とはなんでしょうか？

Comment: GHCが「型を決定できない！」と嘆いているのは`color`の型ではなく`getFromInt 1`の型です。なので、 `(getFromInt 1  :: Color)` と書くのが正解です。エラーメッセージにおいても`getFromInt 1` の箇所に `^^^` が引かれてますよね？それから、`a0`というのは、主に今回のように、型を決定できなかったときに自動で作る仮の型変数です。内部的なものがエラーメッセージに出てしまうのでいささかわかりづらく感じられるかも知れませんが、複数作られた場合などは、番号によって区別しないとわかりづらくなる恐れがあるので...

Comment: （回答について具体的な修正方法を追記して、修正依頼しました）

Comment: ありがとうございます。実際に動くことを確認しました。あと数名が"承認"すれば回答に反映されるはずです

Comment: @YAMAMOTOYuji  ありがとうございました．